# Xcode: Greying Out Already Touched Buttons

Tags: xcode5, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my app I need the user to be able to swipe a 20 buttons as fast as possible. I have set up the the UIswipegesture but I don't know how to change the colour of the button or just make it disappear once it has been swiped the right way. e.g. The first button says left<< and it has 2 swipe gestures on it I need the button to disappear or change colour once the user has swiped left.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Swipe one button, hide all 20 buttons?

Comment: no, once any of the buttons have been swiped correctly they need to be greyed out. @hoptqVN.dev

Comment: You can look my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set background colour of UIButton by
btnYourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];

Or you can hide the button by

btnYourButton.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 1):

Declare in your .h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{    
    NSMutableArray *arrButtonsInView;
}
-(void)handleSwipe : (UIGestureRecognizer*) gr;
```

In ViewDidload of your .m, add bellow code

```
arrButtonsInView = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id i in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([i isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

        UIButton *btn = i;
        btn.tag = [[self.view subviews] indexOfObject:i];
        [arrButtonsInView addObject:btn];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *sw = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
        sw.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [btn addGestureRecognizer:sw];
    }
}
```

And implement -(void)handleSwipe : (UIGestureRecognizer*) gr;

```
-(void)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    UIButton *btn = [arrButtonsInView objectAtIndex:gr.view.tag];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
}
```